# template is not updated when model change in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I do not know why when I click on Submit button `$scope.result` get the value (printed out by console.log) but it do not print out any thing by `{{result}}` in the template while `{{countDown}}` is still work ok. How to fix it?, thanks

SCRIPT:

```
angular.module('mean.system').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'Global', $timeout', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, Global, $timeout, $http, $location) {

    $scope.findFriend = function() {
        $scope.result = "submit button is clicked";
        console.log($scope.result);  //submit button is clicked
    }
    $scope.countDown = 10;  
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
         $scope.countDown--;
         $scope.$apply();
    }, 1000); 

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-controller="HeaderController">
  <div> {{countDown}} </div>
  <form ng-submit="findFriend()"> 
     <input type="email" ng-model="friendEmail">
     <input type="submit" value="Find">
  </form>
</div>

<section data-ng-controller="HeaderController">
    <div> Confirm: {{result}} </div>
    <div> {{countDown}} </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why have you declared `data-ng-controller="HeaderController"` twice. This would create 2 controller instances with independent scopes.

Comment: @Chandermani >> Actually, I have two templates. The first one is used for navigation bar (this is never change). The second one is used for partial view (ng-view). So I have to use one Controller for two templates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem, other then the previous comment that you were using two controllers, but also, by having your  outside of your initial  that has the controller on it, then that's outside of the scope.

What you want to do is put the  inside the . Here's how it should look along with a fiddle that shows this working for you.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div>{{countDown}}</div>
    <form ng-submit="findFriend()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="friendEmail" />
        <input type="submit" value="Find" />
    </form>
    <div>Confirm: {{result}}</div>
    <div>{{countDown}}</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1792/

And to be detail oriented, make sure to self close your  tags, it's better formed HTML.

---

To be able to pass variables between different controllers, you can do it using a service as mentioned in the comment, this is a good simple example:
    https://gist.github.com/exclsr/3595424

Cheers.

Comment: >>  Actually, I have two templates. The first one is used for navigation bar (this is never change). The second one is used for partial view (ng-view). So I have to use one Controller for two templates.

Comment: Then you may want to use a sort of "sharedService" that can pass variables between the controllers... given that even if they are the same controller, having too instances of them, then they are different.